# Does AWS IoT have Enterprise Mobility Management Capabilities?

Tags: aws-iot

I'm new to AWS IoT and I'm currently going through the capabilities of it in order to use it with one of my projects.

In my project I need to control Android and iOS devices. What I mean by control is I need to ring or mute the devices, send notifications to the device, blacklist/whitelist certain installed applications. Basically I'm looking for [EMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_mobility_management) capabilities. Can I do this Amazon IoT?

I found this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/02/aws-iot-now-supported-in-aws-mobile-sdk-for-android/), but it seems that I can only create the connection between the AWS IoT server and the device via MQTT publisher/subscriber pattern. I wonder this could call the Android device APIs.

I found that WSO2 IoT Server and Air Watch allow this but I would like to know whether AWS IoT allows this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

AWS IoT doesn't call device APIs, only your app can. Any cloud backend can be made to work, since you are writing the code that calls the EMM APIs. AWS IoT is just for communicating between you and your backend code in the cloud.

You may also need to use AWS SNS (in addition to IoT) if you want to send push notifications.